# Project Management Set Up using Lists

Tags: list, permissions

Wondering if you can help.

I'm trying to set up Sharepoint to help with project managment. I am looking at overall project tracking more so than day to day project management. I have 1 client and maybe 250 projects per year with external teams working on those projects.

I would like to set up a list item per project but only show the project team the list items (projects) they are working on. Also, I want to exclude some columns from view depending on the user (only certain users see budgets/ feedback).

I would like to integrate a project planning tool for external users to use (the project team rather than myself)

I would like to automate a survey send when the status of an item of a list changes - e.g. when the project is completed, send two different post project surveys to different column members.

Can anyone advise if this is possible, and best approach?